# C# and Regex - Unrecognized grouping construct

Tags: c#, regex

Currently working on my thesis for a client/server app. I've run into a snag were the server receives information like this:

```
ProToCooL,unknown|DESKTOP-29COFES,10.20.9.53|Hewlett-Packard,179C,PCWJA001X3UHII,KBC Version 42.32|i5-3320M,2.60GHz,2,4,256,3072,U3E1,GenuineIntel|{2,(IDT High Definition Audio CODEC,IDT),(Intel(R) Display Audio,Intel(R) Corporation)}|{2,(Samsung,003355A3,M471B5773DH0-CH9  ,24,2147483648,1333),(Hynix/Hyundai,467CA639,HMT351S6EFR8A-PB  ,24,4294967296,1333)}|{1,(IDE,Hitachi HTS725050A7E630,      FT51009Y7J61BK,3,733004892,476937.531738281)}|{7,(Send To OneNote 2013,False,Local,Send to Microsoft OneNote 15 Driver),(Microsoft XPS Document Writer,False,Local,Microsoft XPS Document Writer v4),(Microsoft Print to PDF,False,Local,Microsoft Print To PDF),(HP Universal Printing PCL 6,False,Local,HP Universal Printing PCL 6),(HP LaserJet P3010 Series (10.20.9.36),False,Local,HP Universal Printing PCL 6),(Fax,False,Local,Microsoft Shared Fax Driver),(Adobe PDF,True,Local,Adobe PDF Converter)}
```

And I have the current pattern set up:

```
\(((?:[^()]|(?R))+)\)
```

which does a decent job of extracting everything that I need, but the problem is that when i use it in C# in this way:

```
if(soundCount > 0)
        {
            string[] smth;
            string pattern = @"\(((?:[^()]|(?R))+)\)";
            Regex match = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);

            MatchCollection matches = match.Matches(sound);
            smth = new string[matches.Count];

            int i=0;
            foreach (Match ma in matches)
            {
                smth[i] = Regex.Replace(ma.Value.Trim('(', ')'), @"\s+", "");
                Console.WriteLine(smth[i]);
                i++;
            }


            IList<sound_chips> newSoundchip = new List<sound_chips>();
            foreach(string s in smth)
            {
                newSoundchip.Add(new sound_chips() 
                { 
                    name = s.Split(',')[0].ToString(), 
                    manufacturer_id = Convert.ToInt32(setManufacturer(s.Split(',')[1].ToString())),
                    motherboards = newMotherboard
                });
            }
            insert.sound_chips.AddRange(newSoundchip);
        }
```

I get an: Unrecognized grouping construct. exception and I'm having difficulties finding what's wrong cuz I don't really understand regexp for C# that much or find a way around it for that matter.

Comment: C# doesn't have `(?R)`. Its replacement is called balancing group. What's your matching rule?

Comment: Well, idk if it's right or not but what I'm trying to match is, all the text within all the parentheses that are contained within all the curly brackets.
{ 2 - suggest how many parentheses are within this set of curly brackest (text that may have another set of parentheses that should be captured completely without going deeper in) }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.NET regex does not support [recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html). The regex you are using ([`\(((?:[^()]|(?R))+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/xZ0rD8/1)) is for PCRE, and you can use it with [PCRE.NET library](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net) in a C# app.

As an alternative, you can use a .NET regex to match balanced parentheses:

```
\(((?>[^()]+|\((?<n>)|\)(?<-n>))+(?(n)(?!)))\)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C(((%3F%3E%5B%5E()%5D%2B%7C%5C((%3F%3Cn%3E)%7C%5C)(%3F%3C-n%3E))%2B(%3F(n)(%3F!)))%5C)&i=ProToCooL%2Cunknown%7CDESKTOP-29COFES%2C10.20.9.53%7CHewlett-Packard%2C179C%2CPCWJA001X3UHII%2CKBC%20Version%2042.32%7Ci5-3320M%2C2.60GHz%2C2%2C4%2C256%2C3072%2CU3E1%2CGenuineIntel%7C%7B2%2C(IDT%20High%20Definition%20Audio%20CODEC%2CIDT)%2C(Intel(R)%20Display%20Audio%2CIntel(R)%20Corporation)%7D%7C%7B2%2C(Samsung%2C003355A3%2CM471B5773DH0-CH9%20%20%2C24%2C2147483648%2C1333)%2C(Hynix%2FHyundai%2C467CA639%2CHMT351S6EFR8A-PB%20%20%2C24%2C4294967296%2C1333)%7D%7C%7B1%2C(IDE%2CHitachi%20HTS725050A7E630%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20FT51009Y7J61BK%2C3%2C733004892%2C476937.531738281)%7D%7C%7B7%2C(Send%20To%20OneNote%202013%2CFalse%2CLocal%2CSend%20to%20Microsoft%20OneNote%2015%20Driver)%2C(Microsoft%20XPS%20Document%20Writer%2CFalse%2CLocal%2CMicrosoft%20XPS%20Document%20Writer%20v4)%2C(Microsoft%20Print%20to%20PDF%2CFalse%2CLocal%2CMicrosoft%20Print%20To%20PDF)%2C(HP%20Universal%20Printing%20PCL%206%2CFalse%2CLocal%2CHP%20Universal%20Printing%20PCL%206)%2C(HP%20LaserJet%20P3010%20Series%20(10.20.9.36)%2CFalse%2CLocal%2CHP%20Universal%20Printing%20PCL%206)%2C(Fax%2CFalse%2CLocal%2CMicrosoft%20Shared%20Fax%20Driver)%2C(Adobe%20PDF%2CTrue%2CLocal%2CAdobe%20PDF%20Converter)%7D).

It returns all those 12 matches as the [PCRE regex](https://regex101.com/r/xZ0rD8/1).

Comment: I just tried this out and it's working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. There is an explanation of this regex at [MSDN blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2005/03/15/net-regular-expressions-regex-and-balanced-matching-ryan-byington/) and there are some more cool examples with balancing groups at [weblogs.asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/377025).