# Regex.Matches throws exception for regex formula c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string value as follow

```
([68_89]+([65_79]/100)) + (([68_111]*12)*([65_79]/([IC_555]*12)-100))
```

If i try to use following regex for the related string value

```
MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(formulaWithPrefix, @"((?:\w+|\((?1)\))(?:[+*^-](?1)|)?)", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

I got the following excepition:

```
unrecognized grouping construct
```

What value should I change in regex to solve this issue

Any help will be appreicated.

Thanks

Comment: .NET regex does not support recursion and subroutines

Comment: For the time being, you might as well use `\w+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you share example according to given string regex ?

Comment: I used your string and regex in regex101 tester and saw that it yielded the same results as `\w+` did

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/34493693/11884135